# Problem when extracting year and week number from string in PSQL

Tags: postgresql, datetime

Let's say that I have a range of SQL tables that are named `name_YYYY_WW` where YYYY = year and WW = week number. If I call upon a function that guides a user defined date to the right table.

If the date entered is `"20110101"`:

`SELECT EXTRACT (WEEK FROM DATE '20110101')` returns 52 and

`SELECT EXTRACT (YEAR FROM DATE '20110101')` returns 2011.

While is nothing wrong with these results I want `"20110101"` to either point to table `name_2010_52` or `name_2011_01`, not `name_2011_52` as it does now when I concanate the results to form the query for the table.

Any elegant solutions to this problem?

Comment: For example, can I somehow specify that when a date is entered, it will return the week number and year of the last day of that specific week?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The function [to_char()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-formatting.html) will allow you to [format a date or timestamp](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-DATETIME-TABLE) to output correct the iso week *and* iso year.

```
SELECT to_char('2011-01-01'::date, 'IYYY_IW') as iso_year_week;
```

will produce:

```
 iso_year_week 
---------------
 2010_52
(1 row)
```

Comment: It is ISO week-numbering year (week-based-year).

Answer (score -2):

You could use a CASE:

```
WITH sub(field) AS (
    SELECT CAST('20110101' AS date) -- just to test
)
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN EXTRACT (WEEK FROM field ) > 1 AND EXTRACT (MONTH FROM field) = 1 AND EXTRACT (DAY FROM field) < 3 THEN 1
    ELSE
        EXTRACT (WEEK FROM field)
    END
FROM 
    sub;
```

Comment: Thanks, but would rather have some code that does without coding for "exceptions". Could somebody hint for a solution that is based on my own comment for the question?